# Dask-ml ParallelPostFit not using distributed and causing memory error on local machine

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe, dask-ml

I want to do Random Forest predictions on a large dataset and save the result as an dataframe. I read https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning/parallel-prediction.html and it says "Workers can write the predicted values to a shared file system, without ever having to collect the data on a single machine", but I cant figure out how to do this. I tried this by connecting to a distributed cluster and doing:

```
x = da.from_array(i,100000)
t = model.predict(x)
t= client.persist(t)
df=dd.from_array(t)
df.to_parquet("xy.parquet")
```

However this does not trigger any computation on the cluster (observed with dashboard), and runs my 1TB RAM machine into a memory error when `to_parquet` computes, even for a test where the numpy size of `x` and `t` is 7GB. Anything else I submit to the cluster is computed there.
So how do I save the results of the prediction?

EDIT:
This seems to be an issue of size for the input `x`. It has the shape `(24507731,8)`. If I instead just throw in random data with the shape `(24507,8)` the computation finished. This is quite surprising as `ParallelPostfit` is supposed to make prediction on large data possible in the first place.

Comment: Are you using `sklearn` for your `model` or `dask-ml`?

Comment: I wrapped `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` with `ParallelPostfit` form `dask-ml`